# Convert DeploymentItem from MSTest to xUnit

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mstest, xunit

I'm migrating MSTest cases to XUnit and couldn't find a way to convert DeploymentItem attribute of MSUnit to equivalent in XUnit. Please let me know how to migrate it.

[DeploymentItem("Test Data", "Certificates")]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

XUnit creators [suggest](https://twitter.com/BeiWang10/status/1000134997641256960) using embedded resources as there is no equivalent

> [image: twitter post]

You can find some details how to read embedded resources in other questions. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) of them:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```